# Email bouncing because IP name lookup failed, but I can see rDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email-bounces

I am seeing a lot of email bouncing from my server... the bounce messages indicate that the IP does not have reverse DNS set up, but I can see valid rDNS records when I query it on my local machine. I know I set the rDNS records at least four days ago, so I am sure any TTLs would have expired. What could be causing this and how can I troubleshoot?

The server's IP is: 209.59.186.119

Here is a sample bounce message, with email addresses removed:

```
xxxxxx@nc.rr.com
  SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
  host cdptpa-smtpin01.mail.rr.com [75.180.132.243]:
  554 5.7.1 - Connection refused. IP name lookup failed for 209.59.186.119

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
------ The body of the message is 3307201 characters long; only the first
------ 106496 or so are included here.

Return-path: 
Received: from mail-px0-f174.google.com ([209.85.212.174])
      by webserver01.venuecom.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128)
      (Exim 4.69)
      (envelope-from )
      id 1Q1dLe-0004yE-VA
      for xxxxx@nc.rr.com; Mon, 21 Mar 2011 07:32:36 -0400
Received: by pxi15 with SMTP id 15so1073240pxi.5
      for ; Mon, 21 Mar 2011 04:32:36 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.142.250.5 with SMTP id x5mr2803872wfh.440.
1300707156399; Mon,
21 Mar 2011 04:32:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.142.88.2 with HTTP; Mon, 21 Mar 2011 04:32:36 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2011 07:32:36 -0400
Message-ID: 
Subject: invoice for reprint/final proof
From: aaaa bbbbbb 
To: xxxxxx@nc.rr.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001636ed678203ac8b049efc7ca1


Sent from my iPad
```

Comment: It would help to see the contents of the SMTP transaction between your mail server and the rejecting mail server.

Answer (score 4):

Your PTR address works. If it didn't, RR would return a 421 error instead of a 554. Your DNS seems fine to me ([Report here](http://www.intodns.com/venuecom.com))

I believe that the 554 error means that your email server needs to correctly identify itself as the hostname in question (webserver01.venuecom.com) when connecting. For example, it should greet the RR server with "EHLO webserver01.venuecom.com"

More info here: http://security.rr.com/mail_blocks.htm

Comment: I just had this same issue, and fixed it by matching my mail server banner with the PTR record - as hyppy describes.

Comment: This seems like a very likely cause, but I believe my mail server *is* identifying itself as `webserver01.venuecom.com`. I'll view a tcpdump to be sure.